# what is data and dictionary in huffman encoding

Tags: data-structures, huffman-code

I have a basic question on the terminologies used in Huffman encoding. I tried searching on Google but no definition is available(some define them using another terms to represent them), so bit confusing for me.

My question is :

I have symbols and freq and encode like this (these are hypothetical, please don't try solving it to check the encode), my motive is just to know the meaning clear of some technical terms used for huffman:

```
symbol   freq  encode
  s1      12     110
  s2      5      10
  s3      6      01
```

could some one please tell me what is data among these 3 and what is dictionary ? Please give a bit detailed explanation. Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Why not re-read the lecture notes?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth programming part is already done :) i just wanted to know these technical terms i fyou could please help me ?

Comment: The data would be the thing you want to "translate": Any amount of s1/s2/s3 in some order, and the corresponding amount of 100/10/01. The dictionary is the information that s1 belongs to 100, s2 to 10 etc.

Comment: @EdHeal i don't have it in lecture notes and on internet they just use the erms wihout explaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary here would be a mapping of `symbols` to a `code`

Actual data is the set of `symbols` and their `frequencies`

In your case,

**DATA**

```
  symbol   freq
    s1      12 
    s2      5  
    s3      6
```

**Dictionary**

```
   symbol encoding
    s1     110
    s2     10
    s3     01
```